# @cannot statement from Blade engine not working

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-blade

I'm trying to use @cannot in my template but I have the following issue. With the code:

```
@section('content')
    @can('upload-images',$flyer)
        <form action="{{ URL::to('/') }}/{{ $flyer->zip }}/{{ $flyer->street }}/photos" method="POST" class="dropzone" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
        </form>
    @endcan
    @cannot
        <p>Not allowed</p>
    @endcannot
@stop
```

@cannot throws the following error:

```
Undefined class constant 'denies'
```

I know @cannot exists and also that uses Gate::denies, which is the error I'm taking, here is the Github commit where the magic should occur:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/9c41aa0d53412e3008285e89ff9764fa51b42469

Any clues? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Laravel's doc has being updated. I should use @else:

```
@can(...)
@else
@endcan
```

And @cannot should be used as the opposite of @can, but never at the same time:

```
@cannot(...)
@else
@endcannot
```

Comment: This is not true. One may use `@can`  and at the same time `@cannot`. See my answer why your code didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the input in the `cannot` method:

```
@cannot('upload-images',$flyer)
       <p>Not allowed</p>
@endcannot
```

However in this situation its more elegant to use else

```
 @can('upload-images',$flyer)
        <form action="{{ URL::to('/') }}/{{ $flyer->zip }}/{{ $flyer->street }}/photos" method="POST" class="dropzone" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
        </form>
 @else
        <p>Not allowed</p>
 @endcan
```