# Laravel Blade Check If User Not Have a Permission Inside Array of Permission

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-10, laravel-permission

Can you guys help me? I just want to know how to check if the user do not have a permission from an array of permission on laravel blade. I think is the inverse of `@canany`

Maybe the illustration in my head is like this :

```
if( !($user->canany(['store', 'update'])) ) {
   // user don't have store or update permission
}
```

For now my code is like :

```
@canany($permissions)
  // user have the permission, but i don't need this section
@else
  // user don't have the permission, but i need this section
@endcanany
```

Because of that, I want my to code in my blade file is like :

```
@inverseCanAny($permissions)
   // do something when user don't have the permissions
@endInverseCanAny
```

Sorry if my English is bad

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try @cannot

this references may help you

1. [@cannot statement from Blade engine not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35114624/cannot-statement-from-blade-engine-not-working)
2. https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v5/basic-usage/blade-directives

or just let it empty and only fill the else condition

Comment: Alright, maybe I just leave it empty. Thanks for the answer